# jquery: div not open up to id-9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i sending you detailed about my work, when i click on the link 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 then all worked is OK, and then i click on 10 then detailed DIV is hide, and when i add one more link means when i put ID 11 then it goes to detail-id1. i just want put id's 1 to up to 100.

See this link: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hassanjaved/hLd5W/19/)

this is JS Code:

```
jQuery('a[id^="prod"]').on('click', function (e) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id').slice(-1);
    var previs = $('div.product-detail:visible');
    $('div.product-detail').hide();
    if (previs.is($('.det' + id))) {
        $('.det' + id).hide()
    }
    else
    {
        $('.det' + id).show();
    }

    e.preventDefault()
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `var id = this.id.match(/\d+/);` **to get the number** out of your ID

http://jsfiddle.net/hLd5W/21/

Comment: @scriptscale sure. Have you tried? All it needs is to put a pair of `100` in the HTML and try! :)

Answer (score 1):

From a first look, I'd say the issue is in:

```
var id = $(this).attr('id').slice(-1);
```

You are only getting the last digit of the id and not the whole number. If you replace that line for something like:

```
var id = $(this).attr('id').replace('prod', '');
```

It may work with any number of digits, as seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/hLd5W/20/

Comment: thank you very much. your code also worked :) but @Roko Answered first .

Answer (score 1):

That's because `slice(-1)` returns the last character of the string. There is no need to use the ids, you can use the `index` and `eq` methods:

```
var $pd = $('.product-detail');
var $links = $('a[id^="prod"]').on('click', function (e) {
   var i = $links.index(this), $target = $pd.eq(i);

   $pd.not($target.toggle()).hide();

   e.preventDefault()
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rLh8G/

Comment: This solution breaks if titles and descriptions are not in order http://jsfiddle.net/rLh8G/1/

Comment: @Monty82 I have answered the question based on the existing markup.